# What is an effective way to clean up gasoline spill?

Tags: fuel-system, cleaning

My gas tank started leaking and left a rather large area covered in gasoline. What is the best way to remove the gasoline from the ground? This is pavement.

I covered the stain in kitty litter and left it on for about an hour and removed most of it, but the stain still remains.

Answer (score 1):

Try powdered laundry detergent. Sprinkle it on let it sit for an hour. Dampen it with hose. Scrub with a stiff brush and rinse it off.